# How to collect data from multiple Models in one ORM request

Tags: sql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I need to create a view which returns summarized analytical data about the user's stores.
At this time it collects only sales analytics data.

```
class StoreAnalyticsApi(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    http_method_names = ["get", "post"]
    serializer_class = SummaryStoreAnalyticsSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = StoreAnalyticsFilter

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = StoreAnalytics.objects.filter(store__user_id=self.request.user.pk)
        for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
            stores_sales = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        if stores_sales:
            stores_sales = (
                backend()
                .filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
                .aggregate(
                    accruals_sum=Func(Sum(F("accruals_sum")), function="ROUND"),
                    sold_products=Sum(F("sold_products")),
                    taxes_summ=Func(Sum(F("accruals_sum")) * (Sum(F("tax")) / Count("tax")),       function="ROUND") / 100,
                )
            )

            serializer = SummaryStoreAnalyticsSerializer(stores_sales)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)
        raise ValidationError(
            code=400)
```

And now In eed to add to the view getting a lot of new data: how many stores user have, how many orders user have in all his stores, how many products user have in his stores.

Can I get all the data in one ORM request? I know there should be a lot of "JOINs".
I have a model User(AbstractUser).
A model Store which have a foreign key to User.
And models StoreAnalytics, Product, Order which have a foreign key to Store.
The models are presented in the most primitive form

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="", verbose_name="store name")
```

```
class Order(models.Model):

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="order id")
```

```
class Product(models.Model):

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="store name")
    product_sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="", verbose_name="SKU")
```

```
class StoreAnalytics(models.Model):

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="store_id")
    accruals_sum = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0))
    taxes_count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0))
    sold_products = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Is it possible to get all data from one ORM request? If not, how best to do this task?

Comment: That should be possible. Does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) already help you?